# HTML script with AngularJS script file not executing

Tags: angularjs, html

AngularJS script

```
Var newApp = angular. module ("appone",[]).      controller("appController", function ($scope){ 
Var  persons = [ {name:"sue", points:4},  {name:"Joe", points:7}];

$scope.p = persons;
$scope.message = "those are the points";
});
```

HTML script

```
<! Doctype html>
<html ng-app="appone">
<head>
<script src="angular.min.js">
<script src="apponesrc.is">
</head>
<body ng-controller="appController">
<table>
<thead>
<tr><td>name</td><td>points</td></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="person in p"><td ng-bind="person. name"></td><td ng-bind="person. points"></td>  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The path to script is fine, I cross checked it.
On run, only HTML output is produced while angular is not. Table is not generated as well.
Can't figure out what went wrong.

Comment: add  ng-app="appone" in body instead on html

Comment: @Santosh Singh tried that before posting here. Din't work.

Comment: Is there any error in the console. If yes then comment it.

Comment: And yes, Var is not a valid keyword in javascript. It should be var(in lowercase).

Comment: there is no keyword like Var in js. Use `var persons`

Answer (score 1):

The issue i see with your code is declaring the variable. There is no Var in javascript it should be just

```
var newApp = angular.module("appone",[]).controller("appController", function ($scope){ 
var  persons
```

**DEMO**

```js
var newApp = angular.module("appone",[]).controller("appController", function ($scope){ 
var  persons = [
  {
    "name": "sue",
    "points": 4
  },
  {
    "name": "Joe",
    "points": 7
  }
];
$scope.p = persons;
$scope.message = "those are the points";
});
```

```html
<! Doctype html>
<html ng-app="appone">
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body ng-controller="appController">
<table>
<thead>
<tr><td>name</td><td>points</td></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="person in p">
  <td>{{person.name}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I got that as var in my file. It was a typo here.

Comment: @theTechApprentice check the demo

Comment: It is a typo here.. I got it as 'var' in my file

Comment: i am asking you to compare the demo and see what you are missing

Comment: check your browser console, there should definitely an error

Comment: take a screenshot of your console and post here

Comment: I tried some other angular scripts  too.. They work fine in the same environment...

Comment: then the problem is with your reference

Answer (score 0):

Did you really closed your script tags?

1. seems you didn't closed your script tag.
2. In your code here the **var** is mentioned as **Var** (you mentioned it as typo so no worries on it)

Your exact code ran for me with only these 2 changes. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<! Doctype html>
<html >
<head>
<script src="angular.min.js">
<script src="apponesrc.js">
</head>
<body ng-app="appone" >
<div ng-controller="appController">
<table>
<thead>
<tr><td>name</td><td>points</td></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="person in p"><td ng-bind="person. name"></td><td ng-bind="person. points"></td>  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

---

Take Help of this following link:

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_controller